# Externalized Configuration not works for Scala's Map

Tags: java, spring, scala, spring-boot

I tried to load a property values for external file, and the property is stored as key-value format (Map). It works properly if I use java's Map, just as the code as:

```
import java.util.{Map, HashMap}

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="config")
class ConfigProperties {
    val corporationSecrets : Map[String, String] = new HashMap[String, String]
}
```

But when I just change the map to Scala's map, I cannot get any value from the map, viz., the map is empty.

```
import java.util.HashMap
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="config")
class ConfigProperties {
    val corporationSecrets : Map[String, String] = new HashMap[String, String].asScala
}
```

I tried both mutable map and immutable map, but no case works.

Does it mean I cannot use Scala's map in the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Spring Boot doesn't know how to handle Scala collections. But you could use Java collections internally and add methods returning the Scala versions. Of course, they'll need to have different names. E.g.

```
import java.util.{HashMap => JHashMap, Map => JMap}

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import scala.beans.BeanProperty
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "security-util")
class SecurityUtilProperties {

  @BeanProperty
  val corporationSecrets: JMap[String, String] = new JHashMap[String, String]

  def corporationSecretsScala = corporationSecrets.asScala
}
```

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot!